# Is it intimidation or trespassing if someone confronts you about suing their insurance company when at home?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, trespass, minnesota

I had a guy show up at my house knowing that I was already suing his car insurance company, for a car accident; he hit my car passing on left while homeowner was turning left into their driveway. Would this be considered an act of intimidation/trespassing/act of aggression towards a victim if he asked me why I was suing his insurance company?

What other offenses should I be looking into also?

Comment: What law do you believe is broken? Re: trespassing, did he trespass? Re: intimidation, it would likely depend on what state you're in because such an offense, if it exists, would likely be under state law. For example, in Colorado, calling someone a name or saying, "I can't believe you called the cops" could potential get you charged with a felony, based on harrassing a witness or victim. See: https://www.omalleylawoffice.com/Witness-and-Victim-Crimes/Intimidation-of-a-Witness-or-Victim.shtml

Comment: I'm in MN, and that's exactly why I told my mom to get the gun, as they rear ended me about a month ago.

Comment: Why would you be looking into any offences at all?  You should tell your lawyer what happened and let your lawyer do all the looking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would not be trespassing until you told him to get off your property and he refused to leave.

In general, none of these facts obviously give rise to any criminal or civil offenses. It is not generally improper to come to someone's house and discuss something that you are unhappy about with them.

If one engaged in conduct related to the manner in which the communication took place, for example, pointing a firearm at you, that conduct could be a crime, but simply confronting someone verbally and in person at home is not improper or criminal.